# Formula to count every cell in one column if its value is not in the other column

Tags: excel-formula

Formula to count all cells in one column that meet a single criteria: their values do not appear in the second column.

Example:
If Col_1={1;2;3;4}   Col_2={1;2;3;5}

Applying the criteria to the above data should count exactly 1 because there is only one number ("4") that appears in column 1 that does not appear in column 2.

(I don't care if there are any numbers in column 2 that do not appear in column 1. Also, I just want one succinct equation. No extra drag-down helper columns.)

Comment: If you only have one equation, then how do you expect to get back a _set_ of numbers in the case that the range in column one has more than one number which does not appear in column two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the simplest:

```
 =SUM(IF(A1:A4=B1:B4, 0, 1))
```

It must be entered as an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) ( by hitting ctrl+shift+enter). This is a more complicated version that gives you a little more flexibility with the matching by using the Match function:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1:A4,B1:B4,0)), 1, 0))
```

Comment: I never thanked you, but this works perfectly. So concise.